# JFrame Output results

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

I'm trying to do mortgage loan calculator with GUI and I want to output results from function calcAnnuity in second window after pressing button "Calculate". How to do it?
Here is an image of my GUI:

[image]

And function, which calculates payments:

```
public void calcAnnuity(){
    double totalMonths = (12 * years) + months;
    double partOfRate = rate / 12.0 / 100.0;
    double tempAmount = amount;
    double payment = amount * partOfRate * Math.pow(1 + partOfRate, totalMonths) / (Math.pow(1 + partOfRate, totalMonths) - 1); //mathematical formula

    DecimalFormat decFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    System.out.println(1 + " Payment = " + decFormat.format(payment) + "--- Left to pay: " + decFormat.format(amount));

    for(int i = 2; i <= totalMonths; i++) {
        tempAmount -= (payment - partOfRate * amount);
        amount -= payment;
        System.out.println(i + " Payment = " + decFormat.format(payment) + " --- Left to pay: " + decFormat.format(tempAmount));
    }

}
```

Comment: Please include the image in the question rather than just linking to it

Comment: There is no other option instead of linking to it. :)

Comment: Then how did I just add it? ;)

Comment: You are a wizzard I guess

Comment: correct. got sorted in to Slytherin

Comment: @msparer OP needs at least 10 reputation to post an image, that's why you could add the image and he couldn't :) keep that in mind for next time

Answer (score 1):

On second window take a JLabel to display the calculated result. On click of Calculate button set the calculated value in JLabel using setText() method.